# Explanation of this modular arithmetic example in "Understanding Cryptography"

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Nothing is more frustrating than a book example that doesn't seem to make sense.
I have been tasked to make an elliptical encryption accelerator, and it seemed prudent to read a book on cryptography, so I am reading "Understanding Cryptography" by Paar and Pelzl.  I have attached pages 244 and 245, and 245 has an example 9.4 that is worked out.  My issue is s.

I have $s$, $$s=\frac{3x^2 + 2}{2y} \bmod p,$$ where $x=5$, $y=1$ and $p =17$
This results in
$$s=\frac{3\cdot5^2 + 2}{2} \bmod 17 = \frac{75 + 2}{2} \bmod 17$$
My issue starts here with the simplification of s:
$$s=\frac{7 + 2}{2} \bmod 17$$

I get $9/2$.

The book result is $$2^{-1} \cdot 9 = 9 \cdot 9 = 13 \bmod 17$$
How does $$2^{-1} \cdot 9$$ become $$9 \cdot 9.$$

Any guidance would be helpful as I just cannot get my head around that leap.

Comment: $\frac 12$ is $9$, mod($17$).  That is to say $2\times 9\equiv 1$ mod($17$).

Comment: The inverse of $2$ modulo $19$ is $9$ since $2 \times 9 = 18$ is congruent to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modulo arithmetic, the inverse of a number $a$ modulo $n$ is defined as the number $b$ such that
$$ab \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$
This can be written as $b = \frac1a$, but is more commonly written as $b = a^{-1}$.

When $n$ is prime, every number has an inverse. For example, the inverse of 2 modulo 17 is 9 because their product is $18 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$; but in modulo 12, 4 does not have an inverse. To learn more about inverses and modulo arithmetic, I guess basic group theory or intermediate number theory would do.

Comment: Thank you!  It seems obvious when you see it that way.  I just didn't have my wits about me.  Now on to page 246.